# It is possible to get the variables sent by Ajax in php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-2.0

I have my form defined as follows in the PHP file (Using `jquery-2.1.4.min.js`) :

```
<form id = "testForm" action="" method="post" >
    First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
    <button type = "button" onclick="submit()">Submit Top Test </button>
</form>
```

The following functions is called when the button is clicked.

```
function submit(){  
        var firstName = $('#FirstName').val();
        alert("Inside SubmitQuery  "+firstName);// Work fine

        var request = $.ajax({
                url: 'php/<path to php file>/processPost.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{title:firstName},
                success: function(msg) {  

                     alert(msg);// I can see the var_dumps here

                 }

                });

    }
```

In `processPost.php` file, I have defined the following two `var_dumps` :

1)  var_dump(isset($_POST['title']));

2)  var_dump ($_POST['title']);

I can see the values getting printed in the  `alert(msg)` window. Same is true in the `Response` tab of the `Network` tab of developers tools window. But I want to have these variables
available in the `processPost.php` file so that I could use it to make a curl request to webservice call. Is it possible to get these variables inside `processPost.php` file?

Comment: post your processPost.php file so that we can see what you have done

Comment: You can already print it. You can use it in `processPost.php` in any way you like (e.g. curl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean, you basically answered your own question in your question. The fact that you have this file:

**processPost.php:**

```
<?php
    var_dump( $_POST['title'] );
?>
```

and your `success: function(msg){ alert(msg); }` is properly alerting "Coder" (or whatever name you submit) *Literally means* that the variable `$_POST['title']` is available in your `processPost.php` file. If `alert(msg)` gave you nothing, or an error, then you'd know something is wrong.

`success: function(msg)` means that, if successful, take the output value from your `url` (in this case, processPost.php), and make it available to your javascript as a variable named `msg`.

Comment: But using `var_dump( $_POST['title'] );` in the php file is printing `NULL` for me. I am wondering why it's printing NULL as the AJAX call was successfull

Comment: But you said "I can see the values getting printed in the alert(msg)" - is `alert(msg)` printing `string(5) "coder"` (or whatever was submitted) or `null`?

Comment: Yes, that is also true. I can see it working perfectly fine with `alert(msg)`.Is it possible to test it by printing it in developer console section of developers tools window? OR Maybe I should just try using it in curl and see if it's working or now.

Comment: You can't just view the PHP script with `var_dump( $_POST['title'] )` because it's expecting a `post`ed parameter named `'title`. If you go to `https://www.hurl.it/`, change the method from `GET` to `POST`, put in your PHP script URL and add a `title` parameter with some value (like `John`) and you should see it will output `string(4) "John"`

Comment: If you add your cURL request to the PHP file, and invoke it with you Ajax function, it should work just fine. The fact that `alert(msg)` works means that the PHP script is getting the variables posted to it when the button is clicked

Comment: Okay, I will try to pass the variable value something like as it is `$_POST['title']` in my curl request and see if it's working fine or not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and you already have it.

Look closer at what's happening here. You are making an Ajax request to a php file. That file processes the $_POST variable and outputs it using `var_dump()`. Since the came from jQuery, the response goes back to jQuery. You have used an `alert()` to display that message.

In your php script, you can use `$_POST['title']` to create your curl request.

Please be careful that you sanitize or validate your input so you don't create an injection hole. Don't take user input and run it directly.

Comment: For some reason `var_dump( $_POST['title'] );` is printing `NULL` for me.

Comment: Your alert window prints `null`?

Comment: Not the `alert(msg)` window. But when I checked `var_dump( $_POST['title'] );`. This is printing NULL. Maybe I should test the curl, call a webservice and see if it's working or not.

Comment: If you try to access your php file directly in the browser, you would not be POSTing the data, so the null makes sense in this case. Only when you make the HTTP request with the POST method and pass along the `title` data item will `$_POST['title']` be populated.